# Merging two time-series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have one large time-series, H

```
head(H)
                 time      e1
1 2012-11-15 00:00:00 14.5640
2 2012-11-15 00:20:00 14.5682
3 2012-11-15 00:40:00 14.5670
4 2012-11-15 01:00:00 14.5665
5 2012-11-15 01:20:00 14.5690
6 2012-11-15 01:40:00 14.5687
... ...
```

and a small one (mWL)

```
                   dt       Date     Time    Q1    Q2    R1    R2 S1 S2 S3    N1    N2     O    T1    T2    T3    T4  M1.1  M1.4 M1.4A
1 2013-04-17 12:00:00 17/04/2013 12:00:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA 4.083 4.193 4.325 5.167    NA    NA    NA
2 2013-04-17 13:20:00 17/04/2013 13:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 4.886 6.227 6.183
3 2013-04-17 15:20:00 17/04/2013 15:20:00    NA    NA 4.107 4.167 NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 2013-04-17 15:40:00 17/04/2013 15:40:00 5.833 6.405    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 2013-04-17 17:00:00 17/04/2013 17:00:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA 6.957    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 2013-04-17 17:20:00 17/04/2013 17:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA 6.088 7.307    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
   M1.6 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 F.1 F.2 F.3 F.4 F.5 F.6
1    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2 6.225 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

when i try to merge both H and mWL, the combined HmW data frame shows repetition for each e1 value of H and doesn't actually merge based on time:

```
HmW<-merge(mWL, head, join='inner')

dt       Date     Time    Q1    Q2    R1    R2 S1 S2 S3    N1    N2     O    T1    T2    T3    T4  M1.1  M1.4 M1.4A
1 2013-04-17 12:00:00 17/04/2013 12:00:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA 4.083 4.193 4.325 5.167    NA    NA    NA
2 2013-04-17 13:20:00 17/04/2013 13:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 4.886 6.227 6.183
3 2013-04-17 15:20:00 17/04/2013 15:20:00    NA    NA 4.107 4.167 NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
4 2013-04-17 15:40:00 17/04/2013 15:40:00 5.833 6.405    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
5 2013-04-17 17:00:00 17/04/2013 17:00:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA 6.957    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 2013-04-17 17:20:00 17/04/2013 17:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA 6.088 7.307    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
   M1.6 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 F.1 F.2 F.3 F.4 F.5 F.6     e1
1    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
2 6.225 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
3    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
4    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
5    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
6    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 14.564
... ...
... ...
```

I tried to use 'zoo' package of R, but it also throws an error for one of the time-series (=H)

```
mWL<- read.zoo(mWL, tz="")    
Hsort<- read.zoo(H, tz="")
    Warning message:
    In zoo(rval3, ix) :
      some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

Any idea/clear explanation to resolve?? thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't simply this work 

`merge(H,mWL, by="dt")`

THe only thing you might need to change in your dataframes in `H` and `mWL` is change the date to `POSIXct`.

Comment: google directs here when searching for "merging time series".  I think that might play into the value and traffic of various questions and various answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following step solved it:

```
#make the mWL into XTS
myXTS <- as.xts(mWL, order.by=as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(mWL$Date, mWL$Time),format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
#then merge with the existing time-series
HmW<-merge(myXTS, H, join='inner')

head(HmW)
                    Date Time    Q1    Q2    R1    R2 S1 S2 S3    N1    N2     O    T1    T2    T3
2013-04-17 12:00:00   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA 4.083 4.193 4.325
2013-04-17 13:20:00   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2013-04-17 15:20:00   NA   NA    NA    NA 4.107 4.167 NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2013-04-17 15:40:00   NA   NA 5.833 6.405    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
2013-04-17 17:00:00   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA    NA    NA 6.957    NA    NA    NA
2013-04-17 17:20:00   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA 6.088 7.307    NA    NA    NA    NA
                       T4  M1.1  M1.4 M1.4A  M1.6 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 C.1 C.2 C.3 C.4 C.5 F.1 F.2
2013-04-17 12:00:00 5.167    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2013-04-17 13:20:00    NA 4.886 6.227 6.183 6.225 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2013-04-17 15:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2013-04-17 15:40:00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2013-04-17 17:00:00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2013-04-17 17:20:00    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
                    F.3 F.4 F.5 F.6      e1
2013-04-17 12:00:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6286
2013-04-17 13:20:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6253
2013-04-17 15:20:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6283
2013-04-17 15:40:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6271
2013-04-17 17:00:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6319
2013-04-17 17:20:00  NA  NA  NA  NA 11.6321
```